# ngx-translate language change is not effect throughout application

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have created the application with the pages like dashboard and settings. Now I want to change the language throughout the application when I change the language option. But it is working only for the settings page where I have called the language change function not in dashboard page.

Experts inputs please?

**settings.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService, LangChangeEvent } from '@ngx-translate/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-settings',
  templateUrl: './settings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./settings.component.scss']
})
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {

  public lang: string;
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    this.lang = "en";

    translate.setDefaultLang('en');

    let last = localStorage.getItem("selectedLang");
    // the lang to use, if the lang isn't available, it will use the current loader to get them
    translate.use(last);
  }


  changeLanguage(value: string) {

    console.log(value);
    if (value == "German") {
      this.lang = "de";
      localStorage.setItem("selectedLang", this.lang);
      this.translate.use(this.lang);
    }

    if (value == "English") {
      this.lang = "en";
      localStorage.setItem("selectedLang", this.lang);
      this.translate.use(this.lang);
    }
  }
}
```

**settings html**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label [innerHTML]="'description' | translate"></label>
  <p>Language for user interface and display data.</p>
</div>
```

**dashboard html**

```
<div class="card card-small dash-warning">
      <h2>
        <i class="cis2-fa cis2-fa-dg-logo"></i>
      </h2>
      <span class="m-t-20" [innerHTML]="'dash.doc_gen_status' | translate"></span>
      <h2 class="upper-case bold" [innerHTML]="'dash.doc_gen_unavail' | translate">Unavailable</h2>
    </div>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule, ReactiveFormsModule, ToasterModule.forRoot(), NgDynamicBreadcrumbModule, TooltipModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
    }
  })],
  declarations: [AppComponent, DashboardComponent, HeaderComponent, SidebarComponent, LoginComponent],
  providers: [LoggerService, DataService, Title, ToasterService, { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }, Resolver, httpInterceptorProviders],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: routePaths.login,
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: routePaths.dashboard,
    component: DashboardComponent,
  },
  {
    path: routePaths.userProfile,
    loadChildren: './modules/userProfile/user-profile.module#UserProfileModule'
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: routePaths.login, pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

**user.profile.module.ts**

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, UserProfileRoutingModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([]), TooltipModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
    }
  })],
  declarations: [SettingsComponent],
  providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }]
})
export class UserProfileModule { }
```

Comment: Is `SettingsComponent` part of a lazy loaded module? I think you have two `TranslateService`, one for global and one for lazy loaded module in which `SettingsComponent` is declared. Can you share your module setup?

Comment: yes, it is lazy loaded module and declared two places. What would be the correct approach to make it work throughout the app from one place change.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's because you import `TranslateModule.forRoot` in multiple places which makes lazy loaded modules have their own instances of `TranslateService`.

What you should do is to keep `TranslateModule.forRoot` in `AppModule` only and any other module who needs `TranslatePipe` will just import `TranslateModule`.

`TranslateService` will be globally available to all modules and it will be singleton. So, change `UserProfileModule` to this

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, UserProfileRoutingModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([]), TooltipModule,
    TranslateModule],
  declarations: [SettingsComponent],
  providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }]
})
export class UserProfileModule { }
```

Comment: @klmuralimohan also one more thing, `APP_BASE_HREF` should be defined in root module as well. Why do you redefine it within lazy modules?

Comment: By mistake defined, I will consider it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: [full documentation](https://medium.com/@lopesgon/translate-angular-4-with-ngx-translate-and-multiple-modules-7d9f0252f139)

Comment: I am also having a component which is using a component defined in different  library. It is not updating.

Comment: @SMIftakhairul glad to be able to help :)

Comment: Oh man you saved my day. The ngx-translate documentation hella confusing. :)